# Create Update Statement that uses Joins or Groups

Tags: sql, join

As part of a larger store procedure I am trying to write a SQL command to update a particular field with a value depending on certain criteria. The issue I have is around linking Joins with Groups.

There are 3 tables involved the initial table holds the ID of the master record in the stored procedure and contains a unique value.

```
wrec_id
1
2
3
4
```

The second table may contain entries linked to the master table
Work_id and acts as a route to the Person Table. 
If it does not contain a value or the value of pers_id is set to 0 then I need 'Not Assigned' as the Persons Name.
If more than one person has been allocated, then I need a concatenated list of all the people.

```
wrec_id,  pers_id
1,          1
1,          2
2,          1
3,          3
```

The Person table contains the entries required in the stored procedure.

```
pers_id,    Forename,   Surname
1,             For1,        Sur1
2,             For2,        Sur2
3,             For3,        Sur3
```

The output expected for the above examples should look as follows :-

```
For1 Sur1 : For2 Sur2
For1 Sur1
For3 Sur3
Not Assigned
```

I have tried various combinations of Groups and Joins without success.
Any help most welcome.

Comment: Are you actually updating data, or do you just want a query that shows the people assigned to a project? Also: What RDMS are you using? Each RDMS has different strategies for concatenating records the way you seem to want.

Comment: I will be updating a temporary table using UPDATE  g set g.[Users] = (select ....

Comment: The RDMS is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use the `XML PATH` expression to combine multiple rows. In this case, you can use something like the [query here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dafe5/4) to show the people assigned to each work project. Then, depending on how you need to use the data, you could handle it either in SQL Server or the calling application. For example, if you're only going to be showing the final results as you have it in the calling application, you could use XSLT to display the XML the way you wanted (if you go this route, you could wrap the entire query in a `FOR XML` expresion, and display it however you wanted).

If you absolutely need to display the data as you have it in SQL Server, you can instead do something like this:

```
select
  wrec_id
  ,case
    when
    (    select
            ' : ' + Persons.Forename + ' ' + Persons.Surname
        from WorkAssignments
          inner join Persons on
            Persons.pers_id = WorkAssignments.pers_id
        where
          WorkAssignments.wrec_id = WorkProjects.wrec_id
        for xml path('')
    ) is null then 'Not Assigned'
    else
        (    select
            ' : ' + Persons.Forename + ' ' + Persons.Surname
        from WorkAssignments
          inner join Persons on
            Persons.pers_id = WorkAssignments.pers_id
        where
          WorkAssignments.wrec_id = WorkProjects.wrec_id
        for xml path('')
    )
  end AssignedPersons
from WorkProjects
```

Although, as you can see, it starts to get a bit ugly. Again, if you can, you might want to leave the niceties of how to display work assignments to your calling application, rather than doing it directly in SQL Server.

Comment: Great response, have tested routine and works a treat, Many Thanks